# Append space and \ character to each line, except the last

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I am working on a bash script where ipset (an iptables extension) requires CIDR formatted entries to have "[single space]\" appended to the end of each CIDR line for input into the set. For example some random entries in the file should look like this:

```
175.30.0.0/15 \
175.42.0.0/15 \
175.76.0.0/15
```

Where the last line without a `\` denotes the end of the list. Using `sed` or any other method, what is the easiest way to append this symbol and the space before it exactly? Is there a reasonable way to write a condition to omit the last slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk solution:

```
 awk 'NR > 1{print line" \\"}{line=$0;}END{print $0" "}' inputfile
```

Comment: your solution does not show the first line of the input. i.e. I only get the 42 and the 76 part...

Comment: Wouldn't it print last line twice?

Comment: @anubhava-> You are correct. And it also had other problems. Didn't spot them because lines in the input I used to test looked so similar. This solution works, which is based on storing the current line and printing it the next line.

Answer (score 7):

```
sed -e 's/$/ \\/' -e '$s/ \\$//'
```

Add space-backslash to the end of every line; remove the space-backslash at the end of the last line.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, here assuming blank lines in-between

```
$ cat input
175.30.0.0/15

175.42.0.0/15

175.76.0.0/15

$ sed -e '$ ! {/./s/$/ \\/}' input
175.30.0.0/15 \

175.42.0.0/15 \

175.76.0.0/15
```

If no empty lines, it can be shortened to:

```
$ sed -e '$ ! s/$/ \\/' input
```

Comment: This does not add a single space to the last line, which seems to be needed.

Comment: @fileunderwater, if you need to add a space on the last line, you should rephrase the question to include that detail.

Comment: @WilliamPursell-> The question (which is not mine) already says so: "..have "[single space]\" appended to each line ... ... the last line without a `\\` denotes the end of the list".

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",sep,$0; sep=" \\\n"} END{print ""}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '{arr[cnt++]=$0;} 
      END {for (i=0; i<length(arr)-1; i++) print arr[i]" \\"; print arr[i]" "}' input
```